# Swift, get drive Icon

Tags: swift, drives

I was looking for a way to display icons for the mounted drives and also for specific folders.
I read all the documentation of NSWorkspace and I found this code but I'm not able to use it to get the icon for a mounted volume.

```
let icon = NSWorkspace.shared().icon(forFile: path.absoluteString)
```

So is there any method to get the icon of the Macintosh HD drive?

Comment: The problem here is that you should get your url `.path` property instead of `.absoluteString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of getting the right path. Disk volumes are mounted under `/Volumes`:

```
let icon = NSWorkspace.shared().icon(forFile: "/Volumes/Macintosh HD")
```